# Alpha channel on my unity shader is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

So I am very new to shader programing (basically just started today) and I got this code from a tutorial on Youtube which works great. It just found the pixel on the edge of a texture, and if so, replace it with a plain color. I want to be able to set the transparency of the color i'm returning.

But it does not seems to be working

```
Shader "Custom/OutlineShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _AlphaOffset("Transparency", Range(0,1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Opaque"}
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag Lambert alpha

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };


            fixed4 _Color;
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTexelSize;
            float _AlphaOffset;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                OUT.uv = v.uv;

                return OUT;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                col.rgb *= col.a;

                fixed4 outlineColor = _Color;

                // This is where I want the shader to be transparent or not based on the _AlphaOffset Value
                outlineColor.a *= ceil(col.a) * _AlphaOffset;

                // This a code just to check is the current pixel is on the edge of the texture
                fixed upAlpha = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + fixed2(0, _MainTexelSize.y)).a;
                fixed downAlpha = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv - fixed2(0, _MainTexelSize.y)).a;
                fixed leftAlpha = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv - fixed2(_MainTexelSize.x, 0)).a;
                fixed rightAlpha = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + fixed2(_MainTexelSize.x, 0)).a;

                // If it's on the edge, return the color (+ alpha) else, just return the same pixel
                return lerp(outlineColor, col, ceil(upAlpha * downAlpha * leftAlpha * rightAlpha));
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this line 
`outlineColor.a *= ceil(col.a) * _AlphaOffset;` to set the alpha of the pixel I'm returning.

Thanks !

Comment: You are performing ceil(col.a), and the alpha parameter can only be between 0.0 and 1.0. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: your rendertype is opaque, why would it let you have a transparent pixel with an opaque rendertype?

Answer (score 6):

There are primarily two things which are wrong here - firstly, you have set your RenderType to "Opaque", which expectedly makes it render as non-transparent. This should instead be set to "Transparent". Second, you need to specify a blend mode to determine how the color from this object blends with what's already rendered to the buffer. From the [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html) on blending:

> Blend SrcFactor DstFactor: Configure and enable blending. The
>   generated color is multiplied by the SrcFactor. The color already on
>   screen is multiplied by DstFactor and the two are added together.

For regular alpha blending, add this statement inside your subshader:

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

For additive blending, which results in a glow-like effect, use this:

```
Blend One One
```